# Converting Gson to Object?

Tags: android, json, web-services, gson

I'm trying use Gson to use with a JSON return of a Web Service. That is JSON return this format:

```
{
  "cod":999,
  "msg":"User Data.",
  "return":{
    "ID":"74",
    "name":"FERNANDO PAIVA",
    "devices":[]
  }
}
```

When I try use `gson.fromJson(json_return, MyObject.class` doesn't works and thrown an exception.
I'm follow this user guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

How can I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //get and set
}

/** get informations of web service */
public static String get(String url){       
        String s = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);                           
            }           
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return s;   
    }


/** return object User */    
public User getObjectById(){
    String url = "mydomain.com.br/script.php?email=myemail@domain.com";;
    String response = HttpClient.get(url);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ResponseUser ru = gson.fromJson(response, ResponseUser.class);
    User u = ru.getUser();

    return u;
}


public class ResponseUser {

    @SerializedName("return")
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }       
}
```

**Exception**

```
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Process: br.com.package.myapp, PID: 1481
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.package.myapp/br.com.package.myapp.act.MainActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at br.com.package.myapp.dao.UsuarioDAO.getObjectById(UsuarioDAO.java:46)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at br.com.package.myapp.act.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 11 more
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
11-19 12:56:23.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Not really a solution, more a suggestion: Since DefaultHttpClient is deprecated, you should really use a library like Volley or Retrofit, which are maintained and much faster. Also, Retrofit uses GSON by default so no extra configuration is required from your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that your `User` class does not represent the JSON you're getting back from the web service, but it only represents the `"return"` field inside the response...

Try creating another class that does represent the JSON response, something like:

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("return")
    private User user;

    // getter & setter
}
```

And then

```
response = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
u = response.getUser();
```

Apart from that, you have to change the type of the field `id` in your `User` class to be a `String`.
Gson is complaining because you tell it to parse the `"ID"` into a `Long`, that's why it says `expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was a String`, because it finds a `String` with value `"74"`

Comment: I edited the post with your suggestion, doesn't work and I added the exception. Can you help me ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva, try also changing the type of the field `id` in your `User` class to be a `String`. I think that's why Gson is complaining, because you tell it to parse the ID into a `Long` (which is an `Object`), but it finds a `String` with value `"74"`...

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(content);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    User user = gson.fromJson(responseObj.getJSONObject("return"), User.class);
} catch (JSONException e) {
// catch here               
}
```

Assuming User class is setup properly

Comment: +1 @FernandoPaiva: this is another option. The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to create another class... However the advantage of my approach is that you can easily add a `cod` or a `msg` field in the `Response` class, in case you want to make use of any of those values..